# Odd jQuery issue when validating fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In my form, I aim to disable the submit button until all fields are selected.

Open this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/37/) and do the following in this order:

1. Write something in the `Description` field.
2. Choose a `category`.

This will enable the submit button if the `Title` field is empty. How can I change the code so that the submit button remains disabled until **all** fields are filled.

jQuery code:

```
jQuery("input[type='text'], textarea").on("keyup", function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() != "" && jQuery("textarea").val() != "" && jQuery("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true){
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});

jQuery("input[name='category']").on("change", function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val() != "" && jQuery("textarea").val() != "" && jQuery("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true){
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't get it isn't this a copy of a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829051/enable-submit-button-only-when-all-fields-are-filled with already plenty of working solutions eg. http://jsfiddle.net/jsq7m8hL/2/ or if you like http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/40/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the emptyness of the title input:

```js
jQuery("input[type='text'], textarea").on("keyup", function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() != "" && jQuery("textarea").val() != "" && jQuery("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true) {
      if ($("#title").val() != '')
        {
          jQuery("#subnewtopic").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    } else {
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});

jQuery("input[name='category']").on("change", function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() != "" && jQuery("textarea").val() != "" && jQuery("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true) {
        if ($("#title").val() != '')
        {
            jQuery("#subnewtopic").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    } else {
        jQuery("#subnewtopic").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="subnewtopicform" />Title:
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" />
<br/>Description:
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
<br/>Category:
<ul class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear" id="categorychecklist">
    <li id="category-19">
        <label class="selectit">
            <input type="radio" id="in-category-19" name="category" value="19">Animation</label>
    </li>
    <li id="category-20">
        <label class="selectit">
            <input type="radio" id="in-category-20" name="category" value="20">Anime</label>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Topic" class="button-primary" name="subnewtopic" id="subnewtopic" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/38/)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you don't check if the title is empty or not. Add

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").val() != ""
```

to both `if`s and it should work as expected.

Comment: Can you please update your answer adding this line of code to both if statements?