# If all checkboxes are checked enable submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I have a simple form with some checkboxes and I'm trying to get it so that the submit button is enabled when all the checkboxes are checked.

I've been messing with some of the answers from here: [Enable submit button only when all fields are filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829051/enable-submit-button-only-when-all-fields-are-filled)

But it seems like it either doesn't enable the submit button or it enables it right after one is checked.  Here's what I have:

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  let Disabled = true;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    let value = this.value;
    if (value && value.trim() != "") {
      Disabled = false;
    } else {
      Disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (Disabled) {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

It's weird cause it *sorta* works, but as soon as I check one box the submit button is enabled. Looks like I have all the pieces there, but not sure if it's something within the `change keyup` or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You only need an `EventListener` to check for changes made within the input (checkboxes). You do not need to listen to all changes or `keyups` on the entire document. So just use `$('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){ ... }` which going to save resources.
2. You have to check how many checkboxes have not been checked with `$('form input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length`. This will give the exact number of checkboxes that are currently unchecked.
3. Now you can use an `if/else-statement` to see if that count is higher than 0 (which means that at least 1 checkbox is still unchecked. In my example I replaced the `if/else-statement` with a `conditional ternary operator` to save a few lines:

```js
$('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  var allChecked = !!$('form input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length;
  $('.toggle-disabled').prop('disabled', allChecked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: `var cond = ($('form input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length === 0) ? false : true;` can simply be `const cond = !$('form input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length;`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss if I change those lines to your recommendation then it already is true if a single element is checked.

Comment: Yes, I typed too quick to get ANY not checked `const anyUnchecked = !!$('form input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length;` give it a boolean true on the not checked condition.  Changed the name to better reflect use. still simpler than the ternary perhaps

Comment: @tacoshy - Ahhhhh ok great! Yeah, I was wondering why in most of the examples I saw there was a `keyup` listener, but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep track of count as suggested by @tacoshy, I have modified your code to reflect the changes.

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  let Disabled = $(".required").length;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    if(this.checked) Disabled--;
  });

  if (Disabled) {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is just checkboxes and not other inputs you can just check the length of checked vs all checkboxes.

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  const disabled = $(".required:checked").length !== $(".required").length;
  $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", disabled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Doing it with array some

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  const cbs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".required"));
  const disabled = cbs.some(function (cb) { return !cb.checked; });
  $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", disabled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare checked and not checked counts on any change.

- Give the form an id (event.delegateTarget)
- count all of the checkboxes (filter for that type)
- count checked checkboxes
- compare and set the property based on that
- scope to the form for the button (might consider filter by `input[type="submit"]` also
- trigger on load to set it disabled if not all checked at that point

```js
$("#formid").on("change", ".required", function(event) {
  let allCheckboxes = $(event.delegateTarget)
    .find(".required").filter('input[type="checkbox"]');
  let checkedCount = allCheckboxes.filter(":checked").length;
  $(event.delegateTarget).find(".toggle-disabled")
    .prop("disabled", allCheckboxes.length != checkedCount);
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formid" action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Alternative

```js
$("#formid").on("change", ".required", function(event) {
  let notAllChecked = !!$(event.delegateTarget)
    .find(".required").filter('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length;
   $(event.delegateTarget).find(".toggle-disabled")
    .prop("disabled", notAllChecked);
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formid" action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: NOTE: This has slightly more code to account for the possibility of things NOT being a checkbox having a "required" class

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) {
  let Disabled = $(".required").length;
  $(".required").each(function() {
    if(this.checked) Disabled--;
  });

  if (Disabled) {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
      <span>Filled in</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Checkbox</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <form action="#">
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
          <span>Filled in</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
          <span>Filled in</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in box required" name="item" />
          <span>Filled in</span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="toggle-disabled" disabled>Submit</button>
      </p>
    </form>
    <script>
     $('form input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var Checkboxcount=$('form input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var Checkboxcheckcount = $('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        if(Checkboxcount!=Checkboxcheckcount)
        {
          $('.toggle-disabled').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else
        {
          $('.toggle-disabled').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        
        
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```